# Labels not visible in the cost tble in GCP Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cost-management

I've added labels to the projects in our GCP Console, so that I can add the job numbers to our billing report ( key: job_number value:i12345 ). Despite adding the labels, cost table shows empty Labels column.

Any idea how to fix it via console?

thanks,
Monika

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Ive got the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Google support couldn't help either, they said they will raise the case with their tech team. Labels shows up correctly in "Manage resources" but not in the cost table.

Answer (score 4):

Although permissions on projects, as well as primitive roles Project **Owner**, **Editor** or **Viewer**, allow to view reports for those projects, to see the billing reports and configured labels for all Cloud projects that are linked to the billing account require the `billing.accounts.getSpendingInformation`  permission on the linked Cloud Billing Account. This permission is part of the IAM billing roles

- Billing Account Administrator
- Billing Account Viewer

See [Cloud IAM > Doc > Understanding roles > Predefined roles > Billing roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing-roles)

To query usage by project label, the `project.labels` field in the Billing Export data can be used.